Jest encountered an unexpected token - Error when running tests with Jest and Angular 17
I'm using Jest with an Angular 17 project, and I'm encountering this error when running my test !
Jest encountered an unexpected token
Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

I've tried configuring Babel and using the suggested settings in the Jest documentation, but I can't seem to get past this issue. Here are the configurations I've tried in my jest.config.js:
Added transformIgnorePatterns to handle specific node_modules dependencies.
Set up babel-jest to ensure files are transformed correctly.
Included TypeScript settings for Jest as mentioned in the Jest docs.
Despite these configurations, the error persists. I'm open to any advice on additional configurations or any specific packages for Angular 17 that might resolve this.
Thank you for any insights on resolving this!`
